# Bundle Identifier mismatch in iTunes Connect

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

My App is named 'This & That'.  Well, that's not my App's real name.  'This' and 'That' stand in for the two actual words I'm using.

In Xcode > Targets > General > Identity > Bundle Identifier shows:

com.domain.This---That

So, it looks like Xcode replaced the two spaces and the ampersand in my App name with hyphens in order to generate a bundle ID it liked.

Over in iTunes Connect under App Information > Identifiers, the Bundle ID shows:

'This---That'

I think that's wrong.  This was due to a misunderstanding on my part when I entered the data.   I believe I should have entered 'com.domain.This---That'

I discovered this issue when I made an Archive of my App in the Organizer and submitted it for Validation.

The Validation failed with one fault and I got the following back:

"The bundle identifier cannot be changed from the current value, 'This---That'.  If you want to change your bundle identifier, you will need to create a new application in iTunes Connect."

Maybe I'm being too literal here but when it says,

"...you will need to create a new application in iTunes Connect."

it seems to me that before I can do that, I will need to delete the application I have in iTunes Connect now (the one with the wrong bundle ID).

I read about how to delete an App in iTunes Connect and says that if I do that, I cannot reuse the SKU or the App name in the same organization.

That could be a real problem for me because I really like the App name I have now.   The two words I've chosen work really well for what I'm doing.  So if I can avoid it, I do not want to do anything here to fix my problem that will preclude me from using the App name I've chosen.

Any suggestions on how I might sort this problem out?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about iTunes Connect, not programming.  This question is far more appropriate for Apple's customer support or some other very Apple-specific venue.  I'm not even certain why there's an `itunesconnect` tag.

Comment: I've read through a half dozen or more questions here with a similar focus; though none of them helped me with my particular problem.

Comment: Have you contacted Apple support?  Or looked through Apple documentation?  Or the Apple forums?

Comment: Dealing with the black art of provisioning/iTunes connect is very part of being an Apple dev. So not a question about coding but not off topic.

Comment: @Gallymon , its a bit unconventional but don't fight it and satisfy the condition . Make your bundle identifier "This---That" . "com.domain.appname" is just a style AFAIK so "This---That" is no less legal than com.domain.This--That

Comment: So, Warren, you are saying go back to the Xcode side and change to 'This---That' for a bundle ID there and then advance that over to the iTunes side and it should all match up, yes?

Comment: maybe - suck it and see :-)

Comment: Sorry, Warren.  That generated several other issues.